# How to get the Reducer to emit only duplicates

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, reduce

I have a Mapper that is going through lots of data and emitting ID numbers as keys with the value of 1. What I hope to accomplish with the MapReduce job is to get a list of all IDs that have been found more than one time across all data, which is a list of duplicate IDs. For example:

Mapper emits:

abc 1
efg 1
cba 1
abc 1
dhh 1

In this case, you can see that the ID 'abc' has been emitted more than one time by the Mapper.

How do I edit this Reducer so that it will only emit the duplicates? i.e. keys that have a value greater than 1:

```
import sys
import codecs

sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf-8')(sys.stdout)
inData = codecs.getreader('utf-8')(sys.stdin)

(last_key, tot_cnt) = (None, 0)
for line in inData:
    (key, val) = line.strip().split("\t")
    if last_key and last_key != key:
        sys.stdout.write("%s\t%s\n" % (last_key,tot_cnt))
        (last_key, tot_cnt) = (key, int(val))
    else:
        (last_key, tot_cnt) = (key, tot_cnt + int(val))

if last_key:
    sys.stdout.write("%s\t%s\n" % (last_key, tot_cnt))
```

Comment: You're throwing away the val on every iteration, you need to make a dict to accumulate the values.

Comment: ok! Can you show me code example/ where it would be placed in the reducer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have committed mistake in few places.

1. This code:

   ```
   if last_key and last_key != key:
       sys.stdout.write("%s\t%s\n" % (last_key,tot_cnt))
   ```

   should be changed to:

   ```
   if last_key != key:
       if(tot_cnt > 1):
           sys.stdout.write("%s\t%s\n" % (last_key, tot_cnt))
   ```

   You were not checking for `tot_cnt > 1`.
2. Last 2 lines:

   ```
   if last_key:
       sys.stdout.write("%s\t%s\n" % (last_key, tot_cnt))
   ```

   should be changed to:

   ```
   if last_key and tot_cnt > 1:
       sys.stdout.write("%s\t%s\n" % (last_key, tot_cnt))
   ```

   Here again, you were not checking for `tot_cnt > 1`.

Following is the modified code, which works for me:

```
import sys
import codecs

sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf-8')(sys.stdout)
inData = codecs.getreader('utf-8')(sys.stdin)

(last_key, tot_cnt) = (None, 0)
for line in inData:
    (key, val) = line.strip().split("\t")
    if last_key != key:
        if(tot_cnt > 1):
            sys.stdout.write("%s\t%s\n" % (last_key, tot_cnt))
        (last_key, tot_cnt) = (key, int(val))
    else:
        (last_key, tot_cnt) = (key, tot_cnt + int(val))

if last_key and tot_cnt > 1:
    sys.stdout.write("%s\t%s\n" % (last_key, tot_cnt))
```

I get following output, for your data:

```
abc     2
```